# Proving $ab=(-a)(-b)$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ using field axioms

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

I'm working through elementary real analysis, and trying to prove the following theorem:

$$(-a)(-b)=ab\;\;a,b\in\mathbb{R}$$

My solution differs from the book's. Here's mine -- is it just another way to get to the same thing?

**Lemma 1: $(-a)b = - (ab)$**

$a + -a = 0 \implies ab + (-a)b = 0 \implies (-a)b = -(ab)\;\;\;\square$

**Lemma 2: $a + a = 2a$**

$a+a = 1\cdot a + 1\cdot a = (1+1)a = 2a\;\;\square$

**Theorem: $(-a)(-b) = ab$**

$$0=(a + -a) + (b + -b)=ab + (-b)a + (-a)b + (-a)(-b) $$
$$\stackrel{\text{Lemma 1}}{=} ab + -(ab) + -(ab) + (-a)(-b)\; (\text{and using commutative law of multiplication})$$
$$\stackrel{\text{Lemma 2}}{=}ab + -2(ab) + (-a)(-b)=0  \implies ab+(-a)(-b) = 2(ab) \implies $$
$$(-a)(-b) = 2(ab)-(ab) = 2(ab)-1(ab) = (ab)(2-1)=(ab)(1) = ab\;\;\;\;\;\square$$

Comment: It seems fine to me, but you just do a lot of unnecessary steps after you apply lemma 1 in the theorem you have an $ab+-(ab)$ which if you cancel to give you a $0$, and then just add $ab$ to both sides it gets you to your solution without needing to use your Lemma 2. i.e. after using lemma 1 just say $$0=ab+-(ab)+-(ab)+(-a)(-b)=0+-(ab)+(-a)(-b)=-(ab)+(-a)(-b)$$

then adding $ab$ to both sides gives that $$ab=0+ab=ab+-(ab)+(-a)(-b)=0+(-a)(-b)=(-a)(-b)$$. This lets you get away without using lemma 2, but your proof does seem fine to me.

Comment: @StevenCreech ah, good point! Thank you! Yes, that would simplify things. Indeed the book had a cleaner approach but I just wanted to know if my approach subtly introduced bad logic.